# How can I make a table that takes up more than a single page?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I've got data that I need to include in a table, but there's a lot if it. I've played with the font size and table formatting as much as I can, but the table still won't fit on the page. Is there anyway to make a table that spans multiple pages with LaTeX?

Comment: Let's see if adding the `[page-breaking]` tag will stop duplicates of this question.

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=longtab)

Comment: For breaking one cell into multiple pages see [Longtable: page breaks within row possible? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78578/longtable-page-breaks-within-row-possible) (at the moment it's not possible)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package (see also the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/longtable)).

Comment: Combined with the `booktabs` package, `longtable` is an excellent option.

Comment: Be aware that `\caption` commands are placed *inside* a `longtable` environment, and therefore the respective code lines must end with ``\\``.

Comment: @Quadrescence What can I use the `booktabs` package for?

Comment: [Does not work well with `two-column`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161431/how-to-solve-longtable-is-not-in-1-column-mode-error)

Comment: @tommy.carstensen it's just a tiny embellishment package that provides a couple of macros for automatically adding extra vertical space around horizontal lines.

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend using the [`xtab`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xtab) package, which is designed as a improvement of the [`supertabular`](https://ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) package.

Comment: Do you have an example for the starred version of xtabular? It is not working with me.

Comment: As Jose, I also suggest the `supertabular` and `xtab` packages. The `xtab` package provides tables that break across pages.

Comment: Do you know if `xtab` and `supertabular` are compatible with `tabularx`?

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution with `longtblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\begin{document}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Long Tabular Long Long Long Tabular},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
  note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
  note{$\dag$} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
]{
  colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.85\linewidth, hlines,
  rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
  row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7}, row{3-Y} = {gray9},
}
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta\TblrNote{a}       & Eta    \\
 Iota    & Kappa\TblrNote{$\dag$} & Lambda \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Foot    & Foot  & Foot    \\
\end{longtblr}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good with automatic table title in the second page.

By the way, to use "tabularray", maybe you should do something else.

For overlef, one way is useful: 
Menu -> TeX Live Version -> 2021.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your overall requirements and the shape of the data in the table, you might also consider dropping your `longtable` into a `landscape` environment, as provided, e.g., by the [`pdflscape`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) package.