# Table Out of Page

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In LaTeX, how can I make a table that takes up more than a single page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/in-latex-how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page)

I have a big table which one page is not enough for. I would suppose that since LaTeX is WYSIWYM (What You See Is What You Mean), it should automatically divide the table into two parts in two pages, but that's not happening! Now:

1. Why doesn't it automatically do that?
2. Is there any way (probably a package) to automatically divide a table into two parts of it can't fit in a page?

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate of [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/in-latex-how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page) question, so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a package like `longtable`. And idd, this has been asked here before.