# xtabular* does not work on two columns

Tags: tables, page-breaking, two-column, xtab

I'm trying to split a table in several pages, for doing this I'm using the [`xtab` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xtab) and `xtabular`. However, the behavior of the `xtabular*` environment (that supposedly should break the two column format and be only one column) is quite odd, *because it is not working* ([as this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11401/7561) also shows).

It is wrapping around the two columns, instead of creating a single column. And, as you can see in the example below, if the text is wider than the column width it get over the content of the next column.

I would like the behavior of splitting the tables of the `xtabular` in single column document, in the two column document using `xtabular*`.

Can you point me in the right direction? Or another package that will accomplish the same result?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xtab}

\begin{document}

\begin{xtabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{5}{p{1.2cm}|}}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
\end{xtabular*}

\end{document}
```

**Edit (Partial Solution)**

So, I've been trying to solve this, and I try using `figure` or other float environment (like `table*`) to make it work. The closest I get was using `table*`. However, as you may know, by putting it into a one big float the table isn't split into many tables.

So, I thought to try to redefine an `xtabular*` that is wrapped around a `table*`. So I make this attempt:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifST@tb
\@namedef{tbxtabular*}#1{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@nameuse{@tbsupertabular*}{#1}}%
               {\@nameuse{@tbsupertabular*}{#1}[]}%]
}

\@namedef{@tbsupertabular*}#1[#2]#3{%
  \ST@trace\tw@{Starting a new tbxtabular*}%
  \def\ST@tableformat{#3}%
  \ST@wd=#1\relax
  \global\ST@startrue
  \global\ST@tbtrue
  \ST@rightskip \rightskip
  \ST@leftskip \leftskip
  \ST@parfillskip \parfillskip
  \x@supertabular
  \csname table*\endcsname[t]
  \noindent\expandafter\csname org@tabular*\expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter{\expandafter\ST@wd\expandafter}%
  \expandafter{\ST@tableformat}%
  \@@tablehead}

\def\endtbxtabular{%
  \ifx\@table@last@tail\undefined
    \@tabletail
  \else
    \@table@last@tail
  \fi
  \csname endtabular\ifST@star*\fi\endcsname
  \csname endtable*\endcsname
  \x@endsupertabular
  \ST@trace\tw@{Ended an tbxtabular\ifST@star*\fi}}
  \expandafter\let\csname endtbxtabular*\endcsname\endtbxtabular
\def\ST@newpage{%
  \noalign{\ST@trace\tw@{Starting new page, writing tail}}%
  \@tabletail
  \ifST@star
    \csname endtabular*\endcsname
  \else
    \endtabular
  \fi
  \ifST@mp
    \endminipage
  \fi
  \ifST@tb
    \csname endtable*\endcsname
  \fi
  \global\let\ST@skippage\ST@newpage
  \newpage\PWSTcalnextpageht
  \ST@trace\tw@{writing head}%
  \PWSTsethead
  \ifST@mp
    \noindent\minipage{\columnwidth}%
    \parfillskip\ST@parfillskip
    \rightskip \ST@rightskip
    \leftskip \ST@leftskip
  \fi
  \ifST@tb
    \noindent\csname table*\endcsname[t]
  \fi
  \noindent
  \ifST@star
    \expandafter\csname org@tabular*\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\expandafter\ST@wd\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\ST@tableformat}%
  \else
    \expandafter\org@tabular\expandafter{\ST@tableformat}%
  \fi}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]


\tablefirsthead{\hline \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E}\\}
\tablehead{\hline \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E}\\}
\tabletail{\hline}
\begin{tbxtabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{5}{p{1.2cm}|}}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
\end{tbxtabular*}


\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

I changed the `mpxtabular*`, and create a `tbxtabular*` version of it, that is mainly the `xtabular*` with a `table*` around it. I don't know if this is the best approach or I'm just wasting my time. But, at least the tables now are converted into one column and are placed nicely in different pages and not over the text. However, the tables are not split correctly (c.f. pages 4 and 5).

[image: Error pages]

Answer (score 5):

Replace `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xtab}

\begin{document}

\begin{xtabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{5}{p{1.2cm}|}}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
(This is the last table row)
\end{xtabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I was trying to show that when the table is wider than the `linewidth`, `xtabular*` does not break the two column format, and just goes into the other column. I thought that when one uses the starred version, it will behave like the normal `xtabular` in one column. Instead it just overflows into the other column. So, is there a way to automatically fix this length? Or should I manually fix the content so it doesn't overflow to the `linewidth`?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define it as a table.

It should read like this:

```
\begin{table}

   \begin{xtabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{5}{p{1.2cm}|}}

      \hline

     a & b & c & d & e \\
      ...
      ...
      ...

   \end{xtabular*}

\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your answer was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other.