# The last section goes beyond the bottom border

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I have my last section which consists only of `{tabular}`, it is longer than 1 page, so I need to split it to 2 pages.

So I have done something like that, hoping it displays the first `{tabular}` on the page before the last page, and the second `{tabular}` on the last page of my document:

```
\section{section_name}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
....
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
....
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But it still tries to display everything in 1 page, thus the lines go beyond the bottom border, and some lines in the end could not be displayed.

Could anyone tell me how to amend that?

Comment: Try to use `longtable` or `supertabular` instead. Both allow tables to break over pages. See the answers to [In LaTeX, how can I make a table that takes up more than a single page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/in-latex-how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page) which seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: Beside trying longtable or supertabular: you can also try to add an empty line between the tabulars to get a paragraph break. If both tabulars are in one paragraph widow- and clubpenalty can get in the way. And activate `\raggedbottom` in this section.

Comment: also, the hacky way to deal with this if you are in a hurry is to just add `\vfill\pagebreak` between the two tabulars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `tabular`, which doesn't admit page breaks, you can use the `longtable` environment from the [longtable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package.