# Make a table span multiple pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I have a table that takes up a full page, but I want it to start on a page that already has some text and then continue onto the next page (i.e. it's ok if the table gets broken up and spans two pages). It is a simple two column table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.80\textwidth} |} 
\hline
foo & bar \\ \hline 
foo & bar \\ \hline 
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I guess I need `longtable`? How do I use it?

Comment: The [`longtable` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) is available on CTAN. It includes one *very* detailed example.

Comment: Changing `tabular` -> `longtable` will do the trick. They have perfect comformance afaict.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

There are a few options described in [How can I make a table that takes up more than a single page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page)

I've put a MWE below using the `longtable` package; I deliberately didn't put the `longtable` in the `table` environment so that it wouldn't float, and would show that it breaks across pages.

As described in @Werner's comment, the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) has a lot of detail.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text- not needed for a longtable

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

%\begin{table}[h] 
%\centering
\begin{longtable}{| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.80\textwidth} |} 
\hline
foo & bar \\ \hline 
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
%\end{table} 

Table \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} shows my first longtable.
\end{document}
```

As a side note, some folks would advocate against using vertical lines in a table- that's a separate discussion though :) Have a look at [Why not use vertical lines ('|') in a tabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/why-not-use-vertical-lines-in-a-tabular)

Comment: @cmhughes any idea how I can decrease the font size for text within the table?

Comment: @Goaler444 try adding `\small` just after `\begin{longtable}`

Comment: Is there any way to keep repeating the table header at each new page?

Comment: When I make a table longer than a single page, it still starts the table on the next empty page. Is there a way of getting it to start from where it is in the code?

Comment: @DanielBonetti:

`\begin{longtable}[H]{|m{0.2\linewidth}|m{0.35\linewidth}|m{0.15\linewidth}|m{0.3\linewidth}|}
      \hline
      \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4}\\\hline
      \endfirsthead
      \hline
      \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4}\\\hline
      \endhead
      Content
      ...
    \end{longtable}`

Comment: How can I center them?

Comment: Putting the caption above the content throws an error for me. Any idea how to do that? Edit: nvm, I just needed to put "\\" after the caption

Comment: I would like to add that sometimes you do not want the table to be split in the middle of a row but rather at the end. For this purpose you might add after each ``\\`` where there is no `\hline` following a `*`, e.g. like this: ``Firstcolumn & Secondcolumn \\* & Secondcolumncontent \\ \hline``

Comment: This works great for me, but for one thing: How do I span a single *row* across several pages? Say you start with two relatively small rows, then you have a huge one. Well, if your page starts with the beginning of the table, then `longtable` will leave half of the first page empty and transfer the entire third row to the next page. How to avoid this, i.e. how to allow page breaks *within* rows? Thanks.

Comment: @GPWR sounds like a new question

Comment: @cmhughes Yeah, you're right. I'll post that separately when I get the time, then. Peace.

Comment: Thank you for this response!

Answer (score 13):

You may try `longtblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. It has `X` column and can be used in two column documents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Title},
  label = {tab:test},
]{
  colspec = {|XX[4]|},
  rowhead = 1,
  hlines,
  row{even} = {gray9},
  row{1} = {olive9},
} 
Head & Head \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
foo  & bar \\
\end{longtblr}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good with automatic table title in the second page.

By the way, to use "tabularray", maybe you should do something else.

For overlef, one way is useful: 
Menu -> TeX Live Version -> 2021.