# How to continue a very long table on multiple pages?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a long table in latex. I used the commands:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}

(..the table..)


\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

However the table length exceeds the page margins and the boundaries and it cuts it off... I would like to continue it on the next page. 
I have tried the `longtable` package , the `\pagebreak` and `\newpage` but nothing works.

I would appreciate any help!!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages?rq=1

Comment: A minimal working example would help to help.

Comment: 'longtable' will work if you do it right. Remember not to put the longtable inside a 'table'-environment. 'longtable' has its own caption-command.

Comment: @Sveinung : Yes, I have put the longtable inside the table environment. The outcome is the same as before.. A long table on a single page which exceeds the page boundaries. 

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[c]{lclccccc}

....

\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{table}


There are no errors it just doesn't work.

Comment: @ekyr you mis-read the comment (and the longtable documentation) do _not_ use a table environment with longtable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle @Sveinung Yes you are right. My apologies, I did misread the comment. However now I am getting this error: 
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \penalty \@M \futurelet \@let@token \LT@@h...
l.607 \hline
            
? 

the same happens when I use \hline instead. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @ekyr that is not a complete error message (and the comment formatting makes it hard to see) presumably you used toprule in the wrong place. This is why _all_ questions should have a complete document that reproduces the problem and in the case of errors the question should have the full error text from `!` to `?` in a code block so we can see it.

Comment: I had edited my comment above. The commands of hline and toprule work fine when I use \begin{tabular}. I did not get this error before.

In my table I also use midrule and cmidrule

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get it to work. Thank you for all your help @DavidCarlisle. I appreciate it! :)