# Longtable not split across multiple pages

Tags: longtable

I took inspiration from [Make a table span multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages) to create the following table:

Gist: https://gist.github.com/orschiro/8bef30b180c2d3f493dc

*(I had to paste it into a public Gist as the code exceeded the allowed character length on this platform.)*

However, as you can see from the screenshot below, the table is not split across multiple pages.

[image]

Could anyone advise me why I don't see the expected behaviour?

Comment: Don't encase a `longtable` inside a `sidewaysfigure`.

Comment: note you didn't have to use an external link you could have made a small example showing the same problem, just using a single column table with `x` in each row and a smaller page size, the example need only have been a few lines long.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I learned to not use `longtable` in `sidewaysfigure` and will demonstrate a smaller example in my next question!