# Table over several pages with left and centre alignment

Tags: longtable

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages), we learned how to create a table span over several pages.

I want to extend upon this by *centreing* the contents of column 1 and 3, whilst retaining column 2 with its left alignment. Take here a simple MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text- not needed for a longtable
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

%\begin{table}[h] 
%\centering
\begin{longtable}{ p{.10\textwidth}  p{.60\textwidth} p{.10\textwidth}} 
    %\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.95\textwidth}
    \toprule
ID & Severity & Yes \\ 
\midrule
foo & bar & . \\ 
foo & bar & . \\ 
foo & bar &  \\ 
foo & bar & . \\ 
foo & bar & . \\ 
foo & bar &  \\ 
foo & bar &  \\ 
foo & bar &  \\ 
foo & bar &  \\ 
foo & bar &  \\ 
\bottomrule
%\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
%\end{table} 

Table \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} shows my first longtable.
\end{document}
```

Now where we have the

`\begin{longtable}{ p{.10\textwidth}  p{.60\textwidth} p{.10\textwidth}}`

command, I have tried

`\begin{longtable}{ c{.10\textwidth}  p{.60\textwidth} c{.10\textwidth}}`

and

`\begin{longtable}{clc}{ p{.10\textwidth}  p{.60\textwidth} p{.10\textwidth}}`

however not yet availed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array package and inject `\centering` into the cell. In the last cell you then should also set the meaning of `\\` back to the tabular meaning (\centering changes it):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text- not needed for a longtable
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

%\begin{table}[h]
%\centering
\begin{longtable}{>{\centering}p{.10\textwidth}  p{.60\textwidth} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.10\textwidth}}
    %\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.95\textwidth}
    \toprule
ID & Severity & Yes \\
\midrule
foo & bar & . \\
foo & bar & . \\
foo & bar &  \\
foo & bar & . \\
foo & bar & . \\
foo & bar &  \\
foo & bar &  \\
foo & bar &  \\
foo & bar &  \\
foo & bar &  \\
\bottomrule
%\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
%\end{table}

Table \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} shows my first longtable.
\end{document}
```