# Remove longtable margin numeral

Tags: margins, longtable

I'm working on my CV and using `longtable` so that the tables can flow onto the next page if needed, but there is this left margin numeral that keeps popping up when I use it. Is there a way to remove it? It seems like it is counting the number of entries on my page. Examples are included. I got the `longtable` from [Make a table span multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages), but when I copy and past it the numeration is not present -- assuming is something with the code I'm using?

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Header
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[headsep=65pt]{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=1.2in,            % <-- you want to adjust this
  inner=0.75in,
  outer=0.75in,
  bottom=1in,
  headheight=17ex,       % <-- and this
  headsep=2ex,          % <-- and this
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}     
\fancyhead{Text} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{}

%tabular
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakelabel}[1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@currentlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{N}[2]{>{\raggedleft\refstepcounter{rowcount}\fakelabel{\therowcount}\makebox[3em][r]{\color{black}\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{#1}+1 - \value{rowcount}.)}\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#2}}

\begin{document}


\subsubsection*{Conferences}


%Table

\begin{tabular}{ N{presentations}{1cm} L{12.5cm} R{3cm}}

&National Conference on Undergraduate Research (NCUR). Memphis, TN.& April 2017.
\tabularnewline
&McNair National Research Conference. Delavan, WI. October &2016.
\end{tabular}\label{presentations}
%
\subsubsection*{test}
\begin{tabular}{ N{conferences}{1cm} L{15.5cm}}
&National Conference on Undergraduate Research (NCUR). Memphis, TN. April 2017.
\tabularnewline
&McNair National Research Conference. Delavan, WI. October 2016.
\end{tabular}\label{conferences}
%
\subsubsection*{Compendium}
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}%
\begin{longtable}{ N{compendium}{1cm} L{15.5cm}}
& \justifying Microwave Microbes – A Study of Food Industry Microwaves, Original Research, UW-Stout, Menomonie, WI. Microbiological research into the cleanliness of microwaves at a local area restaurant and heartiness of microbes to withstand multiple prolonged discharges of microwaves within a commercial microwave oven. Advisor: Dr. Jim Burrit. Co-Researchers: Abigail Broderdorf and Craig Warminski. Research Spring, 2014.
\tabularnewline
& \justifying An Introduction to GMOs, Original Work, UW-Stout, Menomonie, WI. Introductory literature investigating the practices of introducing genetically modified food products into agricultural systems and the claimed effects on personal health and economic downfalls with supportive literature on how to curtail possible devastating side effects of improper introduction to ecology. (Recovered media file). Literature Review Spring 2013.
%\caption{Academics Table} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
\ref{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\label{compendium}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While seeing if I could move thing around for the section gap problem, I see that if you stop the longtable and start it again on the next entry, that the numeral will appear multiple times on the page. It creates a new larger gap between each item, but does not interrupt the reverse row count. I will upload an image.

Comment: as shown in the answer, the number isn't coming from longtable but from the `\ref{tab:myfirstlongtable}` that you have in the document, so just removing that is a possibility, but I wonder what was the intention of that `\ref, perhaps you wanted something else there?

Answer (score 2):

The marked `6` in your screenshot comes from the line

```
\ref{tab:myfirstlongtable}
```

in your code.  Just comment it out or delete it ...

So with the following slightly changed code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Header
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[headsep=65pt]{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=1.2in,            % <-- you want to adjust this
  inner=0.75in,
  outer=0.75in,
  bottom=1in,
  headheight=17ex,       % <-- and this
  headsep=2ex,          % <-- and this
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}     
\fancyhead{Text} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{}

%tabular
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakelabel}[1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@currentlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{N}[2]{>{\raggedleft\refstepcounter{rowcount}\fakelabel{\therowcount}\makebox[3em][r]{\color{black}\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{#1}+1 - \value{rowcount}.)}\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#2}}

\begin{document}


\subsubsection*{Conferences}


%Table

\begin{tabular}{ N{presentations}{1cm} L{12.5cm} R{3cm}}

&National Conference on Undergraduate Research (NCUR). Memphis, TN.& April 2017.
\tabularnewline
&McNair National Research Conference. Delavan, WI. October &2016.
\end{tabular}\label{presentations}
%
\subsubsection*{test}
\begin{tabular}{ N{conferences}{1cm} L{15.5cm}}
&National Conference on Undergraduate Research (NCUR). Memphis, TN. April 2017.
\tabularnewline
&McNair National Research Conference. Delavan, WI. October 2016.
\end{tabular}\label{conferences}
%
\subsubsection*{Compendium}
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}%
\begin{longtable}{ N{compendium}{1cm} L{15.5cm}}
& \justifying Microwave Microbes – A Study of Food Industry Microwaves, Original Research, UW-Stout, Menomonie, WI. Microbiological research into the cleanliness of microwaves at a local area restaurant and heartiness of microbes to withstand multiple prolonged discharges of microwaves within a commercial microwave oven. Advisor: Dr. Jim Burrit. Co-Researchers: Abigail Broderdorf and Craig Warminski. Research Spring, 2014.
\tabularnewline
& \justifying An Introduction to GMOs, Original Work, UW-Stout, Menomonie, WI. Introductory literature investigating the practices of introducing genetically modified food products into agricultural systems and the claimed effects on personal health and economic downfalls with supportive literature on how to curtail possible devastating side effects of improper introduction to ecology. (Recovered media file). Literature Review Spring 2013.
%\caption{Academics Table} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
%\ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} % <=================================================
\label{compendium}}

\end{document}
```

The result is then:

[image]

the unwanted `6` is gone (it is a reference to label `\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}` resulting as `6`.