# Use longtable to split table into two pages, but gives an error

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to show a table in my LaTeX document. I want the table can split into 2 pages. My code gives empty space after lorem ipsum, and the table start at new page. This is my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=2.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\theoremstyle{definition}%tegak hurufnya
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{example}
    This is the examples of t-norm and t-conorm.
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{Example of t-norm and t-conorm}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
            \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|c|c|}
                \hline
                \hfill \textbf{Name}\hfill \strut&\textbf{t-norm}&\textbf{t-conorm}\\
                \hline
                Standard intersection/ standard union&\newline$T_m(x,y)=\min(x,y)$&$C_m(x,y)=\max(x,y)$\\
                \hline
                Bounded sum&$T_b(x,y)=\max(0,x+y-1)$&$C_b(x,y)=\min(1,x+y)$\\
                \hline
                Algebraic product/ Algebraic sum&$T_p(x,y)=xy$&$C_p(x,y)=x+y-xy$\\
                \hline
                Drastic&$T_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{if }x=1\\
                    x&\text{if }y=1\\
                    0&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$
                &
                $C_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{if }x=0\\
                    x&\text{if }y=0\\
                    1&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Nilpotent minimum/ Nilpotent maximum&$T_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \min(x,y)&\text{if }x+y> 1\\
                    0&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \max(x,y)&\text{if }x+y<1\\
                    1&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Hamacher product/ Einstein sum&$T_{H_0}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    0&\text{if }x=y=0\\
                    \dfrac{xy}{x+y-xy}&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{H_2}(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y}{1+xy}
                $
                \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \label{tabelnorma}
        }
    \end{table}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

I have read about splitting table into 2 pages at [Make a table span multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages). I try to use `longtable` as below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=2.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\theoremstyle{definition}%tegak hurufnya
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{example}
    This is the examples of t-norm and t-conorm.
    %\begin{table}[h!]
        %\centering
        %\caption{Example of t-norm and t-conorm} moved into longtable
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
            \begin{longtable}{|m{2cm}|c|c|}
                \caption{Example of t-norm and t-conorm}
                \hline
                \hfill \textbf{Name}\hfill \strut&\textbf{t-norm}&\textbf{t-conorm}\\
                \hline
                Standard intersection/ standard union&\newline$T_m(x,y)=\min(x,y)$&$C_m(x,y)=\max(x,y)$\\
                \hline
                Bounded sum&$T_b(x,y)=\max(0,x+y-1)$&$C_b(x,y)=\min(1,x+y)$\\
                \hline
                Algebraic product/ Algebraic sum&$T_p(x,y)=xy$&$C_p(x,y)=x+y-xy$\\
                \hline
                Drastic&$T_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{if }x=1\\
                    x&\text{if }y=1\\
                    0&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$
                &
                $C_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{if }x=0\\
                    x&\text{if }y=0\\
                    1&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Nilpotent minimum/ Nilpotent maximum&$T_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \min(x,y)&\text{if }x+y> 1\\
                    0&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \max(x,y)&\text{if }x+y<1\\
                    1&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Hamacher product/ Einstein sum&$T_{H_0}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    0&\text{if }x=y=0\\
                    \dfrac{xy}{x+y-xy}&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{H_2}(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y}{1+xy}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                \label{tabelnorma}
            \end{longtable}
        }
    %\end{table}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

I have used `longtable`, but in this code gives me an error and I can't split the table into two pages.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Add the missing `\\ `right after the `\caption` command. Also, remove the `resizebox`. Apart from causing inconsistent font sizes when used on tables, here it also causes an error essage. There are better ways to make sure your table fits into the textwidth such as manually decreasing the fonts size (and if needed the value of `\tabcolsep`) or switching to `xltabular`.

Comment: You can't use `\resizebox` around the `longtable` if you want it to split across pages. You shouldn't use `\resizebox` around tables anyway, as that gives non-matching text sizes which is considered bad practice in typography.

Comment: I still want to use ```\resizebox``` because I want to fit the table in my paper size, and I want to split the table into two pages.

Comment: Then redesign your table. `\resizebox` is never the answer and a box like that cannot be broken across pages anyway

Comment: Using resizebox to justify a table is like justifying paragraphs by changing the font size to arbitrarily large or small sizes to make things fit. You should never do that it means that you lose all control over consistent formatting. (for longtable it is not an option as it can not work at all inside any kind of box)

Comment: To make the table as wide as the textwidth, you can use the `xltabular` package instead of `longtable`:  `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|c|c|}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following MWE, I used `xltabular` instead of resizing a `longtable`. Additionally, I also added the missing `\\`   to make the code compilable. Some further changes are commented in the example code below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=2.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{array} % already loaded by xltabular
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xltabular} % Replaced longtable with xltabular to make table as wide as the textwidth.
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % To vertically center the contents of the cells
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace} % improved vertical spacing around cell's contents
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}
\theoremstyle{definition}%tegak hurufnya
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{example}
    This is the examples of t-norm and t-conorm.
%        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ % removed resizebox
%            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
            \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}0{X}|0c|0c|} % Replaced longtable with xltabular to make table as wide as the textwidth.
                \caption{Example of t-norm and t-conorm}\label{tabelnorma} \\ % added missing \\ here.
                \hline
                \centering \textbf{Name}&\textbf{t-norm}&\textbf{t-conorm}\\ % replaced \hfill with \centering
                \hline
                Standard intersection/ standard union&\newline$T_m(x,y)=\min(x,y)$&$C_m(x,y)=\max(x,y)$\\
                \hline
                Bounded sum&$T_b(x,y)=\max(0,x+y-1)$&$C_b(x,y)=\min(1,x+y)$\\
                \hline
                Algebraic product/ Algebraic sum&$T_p(x,y)=xy$&$C_p(x,y)=x+y-xy$\\
                \hline
                Drastic&$T_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{if }x=1\\
                    x&\text{if }y=1\\
                    0&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$
                &
                $C_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{if }x=0\\
                    x&\text{if }y=0\\
                    1&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Nilpotent minimum/ Nilpotent maximum&$T_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \min(x,y)&\text{if }x+y> 1\\
                    0&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \max(x,y)&\text{if }x+y<1\\
                    1&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Hamacher product/ Einstein sum&$T_{H_0}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    0&\text{if }x=y=0\\
                    \dfrac{xy}{x+y-xy}&\text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{H_2}(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y}{1+xy}
                $
                \\
                \hline
%                \label{tabelnorma} % moved label to the caption to avoid overly long vertical lines
            \end{xltabular}
        }
\end{example}
\end{document}
```