# Multipage table doesn't display two standalone documents completely

Tags: xetex, longtable, standalone

I have two *standalone* documents which are essentially two string lists that I want to display one beside the other within a two column multipage table.

Right now I'm using the package *longtable* and it looks like I'm getting there, but, the table looks like floating over the page and it only displays the first records from both document lists instead of breaking into the following pages:  Here's a code excerpt:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{(\textwidth-0.5in)/2} | p{(\textwidth-0.5in)/2}}
  \input{first_standalone_document_string_list} &
  \input{second_standalone_document_string_list}
\end{longtable}
```

I already took a look at the following question, but it didn't help much...

> [Make a table span multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages)

Comment: Longtable can only insert a pagebreak between table rows, not within them. Your table currently only contains one table row, hence the overflow.

Comment: Probably a package dedicated to parallel typesetting, such as paracol is better suited for your purpose.

Comment: Great! paracol worked like a charm!  Thank you!