# How to convert multiple tables in long table in multiple pages with continue tag?

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable, page-breaking

I am working on a long table, the table data and format of the conference looks like this:

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen,camera-ready,acmlarge]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption {Test
}\label{Tab:dcnnarchitectures}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.2mm}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\resizebox*{16cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{p{6 cm}cccp{6cm}}
\Xhline{1pt}

\footnotesize Title & \footnotesize Ref & \footnotesize Year & \footnotesize Category &\footnotesize Content \\
\Xhline{1pt}

\hline

{\footnotesize Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor } 
& \raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt]{\footnotesize \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}} 
& \raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt]{\footnotesize 2021} & \raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt]{\footnotesize \shortstack [c] {Learning \\ Systems}} 
& \footnotesize Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor \\



\hline

{\footnotesize Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor } 
& \raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt]{\footnotesize \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}} 
& \raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt]{\footnotesize 2021} & \raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt]{\footnotesize Survey} 
& \footnotesize Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor \\

\hline

{\footnotesize Federated Learning for Smart Healthcare: A Survey } 
& \raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt]{\footnotesize \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}} 
& \raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt]{\footnotesize 2021} & \raisebox{-3.3ex}[0pt]{\footnotesize Survey} 
& \footnotesize Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor \\




\Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

The table looks like this:

[image]

But the issue is, the table is quite long ( around 100 rows ), How I can split this table into multiple tables on pages with tags continue such as :

```
table 1 : Test
table 1 : Test ( Continue )  ( next page )
table 1 : Test ( Continue )  ( next page )
table 1 : Test ( Continue )  ( next page )
```

etc.

I checked this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages) but I already created the table with different types for each row, How to convert this table into a long table with continuing tag?

Comment: What do you mean by tag? Clickable PDF hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use long table as is provided by `\tabularray` package (version 2021P or recent 2021Q). It offer columns specifications which make all `raisebox`, `\footnotesize` commands  superfluous (see MWE below).

By help of your editor is relatively simple to remove all clutter in table code. Of course, this need some effort. It is worth to invest this effort. Table code will become much more clear, shorter and concise. All desired features of table will be automatically present.

```
%\documentclass[manuscript,screen,camera-ready,acmlarge]{acmart}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\onecolumn
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Test},
  label = {Tab:dcnnarchitectures},
                ]
                {
    rowhead=1,
    hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, hline{3-Y},
    colsep = 3pt,
    colspec = {@{} X[j,h] Q[c,m] Q[c,m] Q[c,m] X[j,h] @{}},
    rows = {font=\footnotesize},
    row{1} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
                }
Title   & Ref   & Year  & Category  & Content       \\
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & {Learning \\ Systems}
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN} 
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
Federated Learning for Smart Healthcare: A Survey
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN} 
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    & \cite{Girshick2014RCNN}
        & 2021
            & Survey
                & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor       \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: It works. I had to separately add the 'sty' file for the tabular array in overleaf.

Comment: @AadityaUra. Overleaf has installed older version (I thing that 2021L, but I'm not sure) of `tabularray`, but to reach it you need to write new document. I'm not very familiar with Overleaf so I'm glad to hear that you managed to install it for your needs. Happy TeXing!