# How to span table across two pages?

Tags: tables

Say I have the following MWE:

```
    \documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \input{glyphtounicode}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
    
    % Adjust margins
    \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}
    
    \raggedbottom
    \raggedright
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    \lipsum[2-8]
    
    
    {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.11}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{18cm} @{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name & 2022 \\
    \end{tabular*}
    }
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

This produces the following two page output:

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

The table lists the conferences that someone added in 2022. I would like to have the table such that it fills in the empty space on the first page after the block of text and then "flow on" to the next page, so that it looks something like this:

Desired page 1:

[image]

Desired page 2:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: could this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages

Comment: I had a look at that but changing tabular to longtable in my code just gives me errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print your text as normal paragraph with smaller `\hsize`. For example, you can define the macro:

```
\def\conference#1#2\par{%
  \bgroup \noindent\rlap{\hbox to\hsize{\hss #1}}\advance\hsize by-3em
  \rightskip=0pt \relax
  \indent \ignorespaces #2\par
  \egroup 
}
```

and use this as in the following text:

```
Previous paragraph

\conference {2022}
Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name.

Next paragraph.
```

Answer (score 2):

Longtable doesn't help here as it doesn't split tables tells across pages.

If you can put the `2022` on the left instead of on the right (which seems more logical to me), you could use the `description` environment.
Otherwise I would suggest the `paracol` package to typeset two parallel paragraphs (the second containing only `2022`).

Here is an example with both solutions.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \input{glyphtounicode}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
    
    % Adjust margins
    \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}
    
    \raggedbottom
    \raggedright
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
    \usepackage{paracol}

    \begin{document}
    
    
    \lipsum[2-8]
    
    \begin{description}
    \item[\normalfont 2022]
     Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name 
    \end{description}
\newpage
\lipsum[2-8]
\medskip
    \setcolumnwidth{18cm}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name, Conference name 
\switchcolumn
 2022 
     \end{paracol}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]