# How to draw horizontal rules/lines beginning in column i and ending in column j (when using \longtable, \multirow and \rownum)?

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow, cline

### **MWE:**

I have tried several times to add `\cline` but without success...!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, booktabs, tabularx, longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\rowcolors{1}{light-gray}{light-blue}
\begin{longtable}
{m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm}}

\hline
\rowcolor{white}
& $Day$
& $Month$
& $Hours$
& $Feature 1$ 
& $Feature 2$
& $Feature 3$\\
\hline
%-------------------------------------------------
Friday
& $5$
& June
& 
& $A_1$
& $A_2$
& $A_3$
\\
\hline
%-------------------------------------------------
\global\rownum=2\relax
& 
& 
& $14 - 21$
& $B_1$
&
& $B_3$
\\
\multirow{-2}{*}[0em]{Saturday} 
& \multirow{-2}{*}[0em]{$6$} 
& \multirow{-2}{*}[0em]{June}
&
& $C_1$
& $C_2$
& $C_3$
\\
\hline
% -------------------------------------------------
\global\rownum=1\relax
& 
& 
& $08 - 10$
& $D_1$
& $D_2$
& $D_3$
\\
\global\rownum=1\relax
& 
&
& $10 - 17$
& $E_1$
&
& $E_3$
\\
\multirow{-3}{*}[0em]{Sunday}
& \multirow{-3}{*}[0em]{$7$}
& \multirow{-3}{*}[0em]{June}
& 
& $F_1$
& $F_2$
& $F_3$
\\
\hline
% -------------------------------------------------
\hiderowcolors
\\
\caption{This is a caption.}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

### **What this code produces:**

[image]

### **My desired output:**

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but math mode isn't suitable to set text pieces like "Feature 1". Not only will the kerning be messed up, but you are also missing the spaces.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot for your comment @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ! ....What would you suggest to repair this thing?

Comment: Remove the math mode (`$...$`) around the words in your first row. If you want to emphasis them you could use `\emph{...}` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do it ! :-)

Comment: Is there some reason for using \multirow from the bottom up instead of the top down?  Not that it matters since all it does is overlay the other rows.  You could achieve the same effect with \raisebox.

Comment: Hello @JohnKormylo, thanks for the comment... :-) Well, there is not any particular reason, I just found quite easy and straightforward to split the rows by using ```\multirows```, and I did not deepen much more this aspect... never used ```\raisebox``` so far.. :-). In general, what I would like to achieve is exactly what I have showed at the end of my question, that I called "My desired output".. that would be my final goal.. and I am open to new solutions :-)

Comment: Multirow does most of the calculations for you, so it is usually easier to use.

Comment: Hi, Anyone here who can help in this regard? ......I am getting quite crazy (and frustrated) about finding a solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {This is a caption.},
        ]{
            colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm}},
            row{1}={font=\itshape},
            cell{2-Z}{5-Z}={mode=math},
            row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
            row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
            hlines
        }
        & Day
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Feature 1 
        & Feature 2
        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & 5 
        & June
        & 
        & A_1
        & A_2
        & A_3
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
        & 14 -- 21
        & B_1
        &
        & B_3
        \\
        &  
        & 
        &
        & C_1
        & C_2
        & C_3
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
        & 08 -- 10
        & D_1
        & D_2
        & D_3
        \\
        & 
        &
        & 10 -- 17
        & E_1
        &
        & E_3
        \\
        & 
        & 
        & 
        & F_1
        & F_2
        & F_3
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you used math mode only to have the subscripts, but your cells are actually only text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {This is a caption.},
        ]{
            colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm}},
            row{1}={font=\itshape},
            row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
            row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
            hlines
        }
        & Day
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Feature 1 
        & Feature 2
        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & 5 
        & June
        & 
        & A\textsubscript{1}
        & A\textsubscript{2}
        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
        & 14 -- 21
        & B\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        &  
        & 
        &
        & C\textsubscript{1}
        & C\textsubscript{2}
        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
        & 08 -- 10
        & D\textsubscript{1}
        & D\textsubscript{2}
        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        &
        & 10 -- 17
        & E\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        & 
        & 
        & F\textsubscript{1}
        & F\textsubscript{2}
        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Coooooolll @CarLaTex !!!! Many many thanks!!!!  :-) So, basically, for this case, it's better to use (```longtblr```+```SetCell```) instead of (```longtable``` + ```multirow``` + ```rownum```).. Thanks!

Comment: @limone You're welcome! Yes, `tabularray` is a new package and it is very convenient.

Comment: Great! Before to start using ```longtable``` I was indeed thinking if ```tabularray```  with ```longtblr``` could be more convenient..... Indeed, According to "Make a table span multiple pages"(https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages) there are two main options: (1) ```longtable``` (239 votes from August 2011 to February 2023) and (2) ```longtblr``` environment from ```tabularray``` (8 votes from August 2021 to February 2023) ...but then, since ```longtable``` was out for a longer time, I thought to use it (just one criterion since I have not experience)

Comment: @limone If you have an up-to-date TeX distribution, there are no problems using `tabularray`.

Comment: Yes, I currently have ```Tex Live Version: 2020 (Legacy)```, but I can also set the ```2021 version``` and the ```2022 version```... Many thanks :-)

Comment: I have a small question about your table... To set the horizontal spaces of each column you used this command ```colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm}}```.....but what is the maximum amount of space I can use (for each column) not to go beyond the maximum page width allowed? (and possibly keeping the table still centered?)

Comment: thanks, @CarLaTeX :-) ....actually, by using ```colspec={*{7}{l}},```, the entire table "stretches" towards the right margin of the page and it "goes out" the page... :-)

Comment: Thanks, by using ```colspec={*{7}{X[l]}},```, the table structure/layout is well-centered and looks fine. However,  the text goes out of the table structure/layout, and out of the page..... :-)

Comment: @limone Please ask a new question with a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right! (Sorry for asking here, I thought it could be a small thing) :-)

Comment: @limone It's difficult to reply without an example

Comment: Please see the. new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676953/increase-the-width-of-a-longtblr-table

Comment: @limone Is Zarko's answer OK for you?

Comment: Thanks for asking :-) Well, I think it is a great reply, and I am thankful to Zarko... However, if I understood correctly, he/she decreased the width of the 5th column (and maybe of the 7th one as well?), in order to make the overall table width as wide as the manuscript text (please see the figure I posted in that question to visualize it better). Nevertheless, as I wrote him/her in a comment,  my desire was to just work (i.e. to increase) on the 6th column, and keep all the other columns still, i.e. with the same width that I initially set...

Comment: @limone I had no time today, but you accepted Zarko's answer, so I think it is OK now

Comment: Yes yes, it is fine, very kind! Thanks :-)