# How to correctly add a "tabular" table inside a "longtblr" table ? (Issues on table lines and centering)

Tags: tables, longtable, center, hline

## Problem & MWE

I would like to add a simple [tabular table](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables) (as described in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables)), inside a [longtblr table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675559/how-to-draw-horizontal-rules-lines-beginning-in-column-i-and-ending-in-column-j) (as proposed/built up by @CarLaTeX in [another stack exchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675559/how-to-draw-horizontal-rules-lines-beginning-in-column-i-and-ending-in-column-j)).

As shown in the following MWE and in the corresponding figure, where I added the simple [tabular table](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables) (as indicated in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables)) inside my [longtblr table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675559/how-to-draw-horizontal-rules-lines-beginning-in-column-i-and-ending-in-column-j), we can notice that:

1. the black lines forming the [tabular table](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables) are not shown, and
2. the [longtblr table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675559/how-to-draw-horizontal-rules-lines-beginning-in-column-i-and-ending-in-column-j) is not centered anymore.

```
% The original "longtblr" table was created by @CarLaTeX in 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675559/how-to-draw-horizontal-rules-lines-beginning-in-column-i-and-ending-in-column-j

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {This is a caption.},
        ]{
            colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{1.5cm} m{4cm} m{1.5cm}},
            row{1}={font=\itshape},
            row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
            row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
            hlines
        }
        & Day
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Feature 1 
        & Feature 2
        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & 5 
        & June
        & 
        & A\textsubscript{1}
        & % A\textsubscript{2}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
             \hline
             cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
             cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
             cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
             \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
        & 14 -- 21
        & B\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        &  
        & 
        &
        & C\textsubscript{1}
        & C\textsubscript{2}
        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
        & 08 -- 10
        & D\textsubscript{1}
        & D\textsubscript{2}
        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        &
        & 10 -- 17
        & E\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        & 
        & 
        & F\textsubscript{1}
        & F\textsubscript{2}
        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Questions

Just by adding that simple [tabular table](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables), as shown in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables), inside my [longtblr table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675559/how-to-draw-horizontal-rules-lines-beginning-in-column-i-and-ending-in-column-j), we can see that the black lines forming the [tabular table](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables) are not shown. Also the [longtblr table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675559/how-to-draw-horizontal-rules-lines-beginning-in-column-i-and-ending-in-column-j) is not centered anymore.

1. How can I show the black lines forming the [tabular table](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables)?
2. How can I re-center the entire [longtblr table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675559/how-to-draw-horizontal-rules-lines-beginning-in-column-i-and-ending-in-column-j)?

## Desired Output for the "tabular" table inside the "longtblr" table.

The "tabular" table should have borders as shown here:

[image]

## 1st Editing, after the @Jasper Habicht answer

Hello @Jasper Habicht, by using your solution, I have noticed that, if I add some text before and after the `tblr` environment,

```
\begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
   \hline
   cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
   cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
   cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tblr}
```

the text in the other columns (but in the same row) goes up to the top of the row, i.e. is not vertically aligned as before. In addition, in the same column where there is now the `tblr` table, I can see some empty space at the bottom of the row, I mean before reaching the `\hline`, i.e. under my text which is just below the `tblr` table...

Please see here below the MWE and the corresponding figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    {\centering Centered Text\par}
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {This is a caption.},
        ]{
            colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{3.5cm} m{1.5cm}},
            cells={font=\small},
            row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
            row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
            row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
            hlines
        }
        & Day
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Feature 1 
        & Feature 2
        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & 5 
        & June
        & 
        & A\textsubscript{1}
        & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
            \hline
             cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
             cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
             cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
             \hline
        \end{tblr}
        This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
        & 14 -- 21
        & B\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        &  
        & 
        &
        & C\textsubscript{1}
        & C\textsubscript{2}
        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
        & 08 -- 10
        & D\textsubscript{1}
        & D\textsubscript{2}
        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        &
        & 10 -- 17
        & E\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        & 
        & 
        & F\textsubscript{1}
        & F\textsubscript{2}
        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

## 2nd Editing

I have just copied and pasted

```
column{6}={preto={\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}}, appto={\end{minipage}}}
```

here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    {\centering Centered Text\par}
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {This is a caption.},
        ]{
            colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{3.5cm} m{1.5cm}},
            cells={font=\small},
            row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
            row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
            row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
            column{6}={preto={\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}}, appto={\end{minipage}}}
            hlines
        }
        & Day
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Feature 1 
        & Feature 2
        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & 5 
        & June
        & 
        & A\textsubscript{1}
        & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
            \hline
             cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
             cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
             cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
             \hline
        \end{tblr}
        This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
        & 14 -- 21
        & B\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        &  
        & 
        &
        & C\textsubscript{1}
        & C\textsubscript{2}
        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
        & 08 -- 10
        & D\textsubscript{1}
        & D\textsubscript{2}
        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        &
        & 10 -- 17
        & E\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        & 
        & 
        & F\textsubscript{1}
        & F\textsubscript{2}
        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

But I got this:

[image]
[image]

## 3rd Editing

By replacing this command

```
column{6}={preto={\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}}, appto={\end{minipage}}}
```

with this one,

```
column{6}={preto={\minipage{3.5cm}}, appto={\endminipage}},
```

all the warnings disappear!

Many thanks @Jasper Habicht!

Comment: Maybe you first explain what the final output should look like. Nesting tables ist never an easy thing. Now it rather looks that you want to place arbitrary code in the cell. If this is what you are after, try to place this stuff inside a box (a `minipage` for instance).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not say that I needed some text before or after that table... I thought it was not necessary and it could make the question a bit heavier, so I neglected it... Ok, I try with ```minipage```, many thanks!! :-)

Comment: If you want to place such stuff in every row of this column, it might be a solution to automate this by using the option `column{6}={preto={\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}}, appto={\end{minipage}}}`, I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution with ```preto``` and ```appto```, in your previous comment, just gives me an error.... Also, I got many errors when I tried to use the ```\begin{minipage}```,```\end{minipage}``` environment.... :-)

Comment: ah ok... I do not know then what it could be...I have just added this last ```column{6}={preto={\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}}, appto={\end{minipage}}}``` in my question... at the end..

Comment: I edited my answer and provided another working solution with your latest code snippet.

Comment: Yessss, now it works perfectlyyyyy !!!!! Many thanksssss :-) :-)

Should I delete my edited parts in my question ??

Comment: The syntax errors you get are just there, because the editor thinks they are errors. LaTeX won't complain. You can replace `\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}` by `\minipage{3.5cm}` and `\end{minipage}` by `\endminipage` if you find these warnings too annoying. Also note that you are missing a comma before the last option (`hlines`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! All the warnings removed by using ```column{6}={preto={\minipage{3.5cm}}, appto={\minipage}},``` :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot the ```end```... I used this one: ```column{6}={preto={\minipage{3.5cm}}, appto={\endminipage}},``` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to nest tables, you should place a `tblr` inside a `longtblr` (or inside another `tblr`) and not nest `tabular`s inside. The reason is that `tblr` (and `longtblr`) environments are typeset quite differently from `tabular`s, which is probably the reason for the problems that might occur if you nest one of the latter inside one of the former. Replacing the `tabular` environment in your code by a `tblr` environment solves the problem with the cell borders.

Also, you should probably not use a `center` environment inside a `tblr` cell. Rather, use the packages capabilities of centering text in specific cells using options. I did not show this in my solution because I don't think that centering the nested table is even necessary.

As for the question why your table is not centered, the answer is just: It is too wide. I cannot help you in this regard, but maybe reducing the page margins or choosing a smaller font can help you. In the end, your table should not be wider then `\textwidth` which is the width of the text body on the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    {\centering Centered Text\par}
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {This is a caption.},
        ]{
            colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{3.5cm} m{1.5cm}},
            cells={font=\small},
            row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
            row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
            row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
            hlines
        }
        & Day
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Feature 1 
        & Feature 2
        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & 5 
        & June
        & 
        & A\textsubscript{1}
        & % A\textsubscript{2}
        \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
            \hline
             cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
             cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
             cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
             \hline
        \end{tblr}
        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
        & 14 -- 21
        & B\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        &  
        & 
        &
        & C\textsubscript{1}
        & C\textsubscript{2}
        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
        & 08 -- 10
        & D\textsubscript{1}
        & D\textsubscript{2}
        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        &
        & 10 -- 17
        & E\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        & 
        & 
        & F\textsubscript{1}
        & F\textsubscript{2}
        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I am unsure what you want to place in the cells, but it might be a solution (albeit probably not the best one) to harden the relevant cells using a `minipage`, so you can place whatever you want inside. Since I take it that all cells in column six should behave the same way, I used suitable options to make future coding easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    {\centering Centered Text\par}
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {This is a caption.},
        ]{
            colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{3.5cm} m{1.5cm}},
            cells={font=\small},
            row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
            row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
            row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
            column{6}={preto={\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}}, appto={\end{minipage}}},
            hlines
        }
        & Day
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Feature 1 
        & Feature 2
        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & 5 
        & June
        & 
        & A\textsubscript{1}
        & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
            \hline
             cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
             cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
             cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
             \hline
        \end{tblr}
        This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
        & 14 -- 21
        & B\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        &  
        & 
        &
        & C\textsubscript{1}
        & C\textsubscript{2}
        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
        & 08 -- 10
        & D\textsubscript{1}
        & D\textsubscript{2}
        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        &
        & 10 -- 17
        & E\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        & 
        & 
        & F\textsubscript{1}
        & F\textsubscript{2}
        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case your editor complains about the syntax (which is, in fact, not wrong as you will see if you try to compile the code), you can replace

```
column{6}={preto={\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}}, appto={\end{minipage}}},
```

by

```
column{6}={preto={\minipage{3.5cm}}, appto={\endminipage}},
```

which should calm down the editor's syntax validation mechanism.

Comment: A great answer!!! Many thanks for your explanation!! :-) 
I am very grateful @Jasper Habich :-)

Comment: Hello @Jasper Habicht, I think there is a small issue about formatting with your solution,  by using the ```tblr``` environment... Please see my edited question... Is there anything I can do there ?

Comment: Perfect! Your edited answer works perfectly!!
I just get some sort of red-coloured warnings in my editor: ```closed \begin{minipage} found at close group }
unexpected close group } after \begin{minipage}
unexpected \end{minipage} after \begin{longtblr}
unclosed open group { found at \end{minipage}
unclosed open group { found at \end{minipage}```

Comment: @limone This warning is because the editor thinks that the syntax is wrong. But it is, in fact, not wrong. You can ignore these syntax warnings. Upon compilation, no errors should be output by LaTeX itself. If you find these syntax warnings too annoying, you can replace `\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}` by `\minipage{3.5cm}` and `\end{minipage}` by `\endminipage`.

Comment: Ok, great, I will ignore them :-) The output (after the compilation) is perfect, i.e. without any errors or warnings.. Again, I am very grateful!