# Increase the width of a "longtblr" table

Tags: tables, margins, longtable

## Problem & MWE

I would like to increase the width of the following `longtblr` table as much as the maximum page width allowed, which should be - I guess - as wide as the text, i.e. from to the left margin to the right margin of the page. In other words, I would like to make the following table as wide as the text, from the left margin to the right margin.

However, I would have a constraint. I would like to keep the same following columns' widths

```
colspec={m{0.9cm} m{0.1cm} m{0.6cm} m{1cm} m{3cm} m{6cm} m{1.5cm}},
```

except for the 6th column (that one called `Feature 2`), which is now `6cm` wide. Therefore, the idea is to work only with the width of the 6th column.

**Basically, I would like to extend/increase the width of the 6th column in such a way that the entire table width reaches the maximum page width allowed.**

**Is there any automatic way to do so, or should I increase the width of the 6th column as long as, by eye, I see that the left and right borders of my table are aligned with the entire document text?**

I hope this is sufficiently clear! Here following my MWE and the corresponding figure:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

% Some packages
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{url}

% Other packages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabulary,longtable,afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\aftertwo}[1]{\afterpage{\if@firstcolumn #1
  \else\afterpage{#1}\fi}}
\makeatother

% Start of the document
\begin{document}

% Some text
\lipsum[1-8]

% A "longtblr" table
\aftertwo{
    \onecolumn
        \begin{longtblr}[
            caption = {This is a caption.},
            ]{
                colspec={m{0.9cm} m{0.1cm} m{0.6cm} m{1cm} m{3cm} m{6cm} m{1.5cm}},
                cells={font=\small},
                row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
                row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
                row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
                column{6}={preto={\minipage{6cm}}, appto={\endminipage}},
                hlines
            }
            & Day
            & Month
            & Hours
            & Feature 1 
            & Feature 2
            & Feature 3\\
            %-------------------------------------------------
            Friday
            & 5 
            & June
            & 
            & This is a quite short text.
            & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
            \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
                \hline
                 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
                 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
                 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
                 \hline
            \end{tblr}
            & Short text
            \\
            %-------------------------------------------------
            \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
            & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
            & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
            & 14 -- 21
            & B\textsubscript{1}
            &
            & B\textsubscript{3}
            \\
            &  
            & 
            &
            & C\textsubscript{1}
            & C\textsubscript{2}
            & C\textsubscript{3}
            \\
            % -------------------------------------------------
            \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
            & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
            & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
            & 08 -- 10
            & D\textsubscript{1}
            & D\textsubscript{2}
            & D\textsubscript{3}
            \\
            & 
            &
            & 10 -- 17
            & E\textsubscript{1}
            &
            & E\textsubscript{3}
            \\
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & F\textsubscript{1}
            & F\textsubscript{2}
            & F\textsubscript{3}
            \\
            % -------------------------------------------------
        \end{longtblr}
    \twocolumn
}

% End of the document
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By narrowing of 5th column? Is this ok, for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can increase width of 6th column only by reducing width of other column. In your case I would reduce width of zje 5th and last column, for 6th column I would use `X` column type, which width is `\textwidth` - sum of rest columns widths.
- For larger width of 6th column you my reduce `colsep`.
- As you can see, in 6th column I centered inserted `tblr` table-

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{tabulary,longtable,afterpage}
\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\aftertwo}[1]{\afterpage{\if@firstcolumn #1
  \else\afterpage{#1}\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Some text
\lipsum[1-8]

% A "longtblr" table
\aftertwo{
    \onecolumn
        \begin{longtblr}[
            caption = {This is a caption.},
            ]{colspec = {llll Q[l,22mm] X[h, j] Q[l, 3em] },
              colsep=4pt,
              column{6}={preto={\minipage{\linewidth}}, appto={\endminipage}},
              cells={font=\small},
              row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
              row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
              row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
                hlines
            }
    & Day
    & Month
    & Hours
    & Feature 1
    & Feature 2
    & Feature 3\\
%-------------------------------------------------
    Friday
    & 5
    & June
    &
    & This is a quite short text.
    & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times.

    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
        \hline
         cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
         cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
         cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
         \hline
    \end{tblr}
    & Short text            \\
%-------------------------------------------------
    \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
    & 14 -- 21
    & B\textsubscript{1}
    &
    & B\textsubscript{3}
    \\
    &
    &
    &
    & C\textsubscript{1}
    & C\textsubscript{2}
    & C\textsubscript{3}    \\
%--------------------------------------------------
\SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
    & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
    & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
    & 08 -- 10
    & D\textsubscript{1}
    & D\textsubscript{2}
    & D\textsubscript{3}
    \\
    &
    &
    & 10 -- 17
    & E\textsubscript{1}
    &
    & E\textsubscript{3}
    \\
    &
    &
    &
    & F\textsubscript{1}
    & F\textsubscript{2}
    & F\textsubscript{3}    \\
% -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    \twocolumn
}
% End of the document
\end{document}
```

[image]

Gray lines indicate page layout.

Comment: @limone, because you require limit size of table with to `\textwidth` (as I understood your question). If table can spill out of text block, you should clearly said so, and also, how much can protrude and onthe which page side (both, only to outer side). If you not like the reduction of column width, just return to your old sizes, but not complain that 6th column is not wider as before .... Is this a problem to you?

Comment: @limone, that is just fine tuning according to your taste. To my taste, the proposed solution gives nicer result (well, concluded from showed table and provided MWE).