# Text out of "longtblr" table borders

Tags: tables, margins, longtable, page, longtblr

## Introduction

I have a `longtblr` that works well when the texts inside the table cells are relatively short. Check this MWE out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    {\centering Centered Text\par}
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {This is a caption.},
        ]{
            colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{3.5cm} m{1.5cm}},
            cells={font=\small},
            row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
            row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
            row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
            column{6}={preto={\minipage{3.5cm}}, appto={\endminipage}},
            hlines
        }
        & Day
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Feature 1 
        & Feature 2
        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & 5 
        & June
        & 
        & A\textsubscript{1}
        & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
            \hline
             cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
             cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
             cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
             \hline
        \end{tblr}
        This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
        & 14 -- 21
        & B\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        &  
        & 
        &
        & C\textsubscript{1}
        & C\textsubscript{2}
        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
        & 08 -- 10
        & D\textsubscript{1}
        & D\textsubscript{2} 
        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        &
        & 10 -- 17
        & E\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        & 
        & 
        & F\textsubscript{1}
        & % F\textsubscript{2}
        This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Problem

Once I increase a bit the length of a text inside one of the last cells, and consequently `longtblr` needs to go to the following page, the text corresponding to

```
\SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
& \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
& \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
```

goes toward the page's bottom margin, i.e. out of the table borders.

**How can I move the text outside the table perimeter back inside, i.e. in the correct place?**

Here following you will find an MWE, which is exactly the same as the previous (nice looking) table with shorter texts,  except for the text in the second last cell, which is slightly longer than in the previous (nice looking) table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    {\centering Centered Text\par}
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {This is a caption.},
        ]{
            colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{3.5cm} m{1.5cm}},
            cells={font=\small},
            row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
            row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
            row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
            column{6}={preto={\minipage{3.5cm}}, appto={\endminipage}},
            hlines
        }
        & Day
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Feature 1 
        & Feature 2
        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & 5 
        & June
        & 
        & A\textsubscript{1}
        & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
            \hline
             cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
             cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
             cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
             \hline
        \end{tblr}
        This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
        & 14 -- 21
        & B\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        &  
        & 
        &
        & C\textsubscript{1}
        & C\textsubscript{2}
        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
        & 08 -- 10
        & D\textsubscript{1}
        & D\textsubscript{2} 
        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        &
        & 10 -- 17
        & E\textsubscript{1}
        &
        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        & 
        & 
        & 
        & F\textsubscript{1}
        & % F\textsubscript{2}
        This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

## EDITED after the Zarko's reply

(I write here since I would like to add also some screenshots)

Thanks a lot Zarko!

I just copied and pasted your code and added a few lines of text in the second last cell just to see what happens:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    {\centering Centered Text\par}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {This is a caption.},
                ]{colspec = {llll 
                             l% Q[l, 4em] 
                             X[h, j] 
                             l% Q[l, 4em] 
                             },
%      colsep=4pt,
                  column{6}={preto={\minipage{\linewidth}}, appto={\endminipage}},
                  cells={font=\small},
                  row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
                  row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
                  row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
                    hlines
    }
    & Day
        & Month
            & Hours
                & Feature 1
                    & Feature 2
                        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
Friday
    & 5 & June
            &
                & A\textsubscript{1}
                    & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times.
                    \begin{center}
                        \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
                            \hline
                     cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
                     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
                     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
                             \hline
                        \end{tblr}\par
                    \end{center}
                    This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times.
                        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
%-------------------------------------------------
\SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
            & 14 -- 21
                & B\textsubscript{1}
                    &
                        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
    &   &   &   & C\textsubscript{1}
                    & C\textsubscript{2}
                        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
%-------------------------------------------------
\SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
    & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
            & 08 -- 10
                & D\textsubscript{1}
                    & D\textsubscript{2}
                        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
    &   &
            & 10 -- 17
                & E\textsubscript{1}
                    &
                        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
    &   &   &   & F\textsubscript{1}
                    & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
                        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
%-------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Then, by adding the `\pagebreak` you have suggested, the table works well and goes to the following page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    {\centering Centered Text\par}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {This is a caption.},
                ]{colspec = {llll 
                             l% Q[l, 4em] 
                             X[h, j] 
                             l% Q[l, 4em] 
                             },
%      colsep=4pt,
                  column{6}={preto={\minipage{\linewidth}}, appto={\endminipage}},
                  cells={font=\small},
                  row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
                  row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
                  row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
                    hlines
    }
    & Day
        & Month
            & Hours
                & Feature 1
                    & Feature 2
                        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
Friday
    & 5 & June
            &
                & A\textsubscript{1}
                    & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times.
                    \begin{center}
                        \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
                            \hline
                     cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
                     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
                     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
                             \hline
                        \end{tblr}\par
                    \end{center}
                    This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times.
                        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
%-------------------------------------------------
\SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
            & 14 -- 21
                & B\textsubscript{1}
                    &
                        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
    &   &   &   & C\textsubscript{1}
                    & C\textsubscript{2}
                        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
%-------------------------------------------------
\pagebreak
\SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
    & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
            & 08 -- 10
                & D\textsubscript{1}
                    & D\textsubscript{2}
                        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
    &   &
            & 10 -- 17
                & E\textsubscript{1}
                    &
                        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
    &   &   &   & F\textsubscript{1}
                    & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. 
                        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
%-------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

So, to my understanding, the `\pagebreak` would be the (only) solution to this problem.

To reply to your query, Yes, my table is quite long, taking 4-5 pages, and sometimes with long texts inside the table's cells.

Many thanks!

Comment: Anyone who can help here? Maybe it is something very simple, but - after repeated attempts - I am not able to fix this issue..... :-) Maybe, @CarLaTeX
 or Zarko might know about some trick here? :-)

Comment: You should be aware, that long tables (of any kind) cannot be broken in the middle of the row. A possible (rudimental) solution is manually break of table before row `\SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday ...` by inserting `\pagebreak`. BTW, I would rethinking about table design. For example contents of the first three columns transform into row )serving as subtitle) and than make column `feature 2` much wider.

Comment: OK, many thanks @Zarko, I will try your suggestions :-) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As I see, you use with exception of columns specification, the code from my (accepted !), [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676953/increase-the-width-of-a-longtblr-table) on your previous question.
- Now I wonder, why you not use there proposed table design, which (at least to my opinion) gives more appealing table?
- By use of column specification from my answer make text in the sixth column far less tall and consequently your problem make less probable to happen.
- From content in the given table example is not clear, why you prescribe width of fifth and seventh columns. For them I would use their " natural" width as defined by `l` column type.
- BTW, are your table is realy need to be of long type?

So, your table, considering aforementioned comments, can be as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{EBF5FB}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    {\centering Centered Text\par}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {This is a caption.},
                ]{colspec = {llll 
                             l% Q[l, 4em] 
                             X[h, j] 
                             l% Q[l, 4em] 
                             },
%      colsep=4pt,
                  column{6}={preto={\minipage{\linewidth}}, appto={\endminipage}},
                  cells={font=\small},
                  row{1}={font=\itshape\small},
                  row{2,5-7}={bg=light-blue},
                  row{3-4}={bg=light-gray},
                    hlines
    }
    & Day
        & Month
            & Hours
                & Feature 1
                    & Feature 2
                        & Feature 3\\
        %-------------------------------------------------
Friday
    & 5 & June
            &
                & A\textsubscript{1}
                    & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times.
                    \begin{center}
                        \begin{tblr}{ |c|c|c| }
                            \hline
                     cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
                     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
                     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
                             \hline
                        \end{tblr}\par
                    \end{center}
                    This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times.
                        & A\textsubscript{3}
        \\
%-------------------------------------------------
\SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 6
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} June
            & 14 -- 21
                & B\textsubscript{1}
                    &
                        & B\textsubscript{3}
        \\
    &   &   &   & C\textsubscript{1}
                    & C\textsubscript{2}
                        & C\textsubscript{3}
        \\
%-------------------------------------------------
\SetCell[r=3]{l} Sunday
    & \SetCell[r=3]{l} 7
        & \SetCell[r=3]{l} June
            & 08 -- 10
                & D\textsubscript{1}
                    & D\textsubscript{2}
                        & D\textsubscript{3}
        \\
    &   &
            & 10 -- 17
                & E\textsubscript{1}
                    &
                        & E\textsubscript{3}
        \\
    &   &   &   & F\textsubscript{1}
                    & This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times. This is a long text that will be repeated many times.
                        & F\textsubscript{3}
        \\
%-------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- as you can observe, design of the sixth column is wee bit changed: inserted table is now in `center` environment
- you should be aware, that long table cannot be split in the middle of the rows
- due to structure of your table, you got strange splitting of second colored block of rows:

  - first two rows are on the first page, where
  - third row is mowed to the next page
  - multi row cell which span all those rows, is in special situation. It stay on the first page but due to its height, determined by sixth column, it protrude down a page.
- as remedy to happened situation, can be -- in the case that you not consider my above suggestion and persist with your table design -- you need to insert `\pagebreak` command before this block of rows

**Dilemma: what to do?**

- Not for me. I would, without knowing your table background, stick with proposed solution which is to my opinion far more appealing
- If you'll provide example of table's rows, which would justify why you determine width of fifth and seventh column and on what basis you did this, than dilemma disappear, but anyway, I strongly suggest that at least consider suggested column  specification (`l`)  for the first four columns.
- I don't know, how to help you, if suggested solution, which you accept, then don't use. So I have a feeling that my effort spent preparing this answer is quite futile.

Comment: I am now using your table structure, many thanks!
I have used ```colspec={m{1.2cm} m{0.5cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1.5cm} m{3.5cm} m{1.5cm}},``` instead of what you proposed, i.e. ```{colspec = {lllll% Q[l, 4em] X[h, j] l% Q[l, 4em] },```, since I needed some fixed widths for my columns.

Comment: @limone, than you show an example, why you need fixed width.  I simple don't believe you, that they are is needed. But, al is up to you ...