# Table spanning multiple pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a table that takes up more than a single page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page)

I want to make a table in LaTeX span multiple pages in a way that it retains the same column headings on the subsequent pages.  How may I do so?

Comment: read the documentation of package `longtable`: run `texdoc longtable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this gets you started

```
{
\rowcolors{2}{white}{white}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{.2\textwidth}p{.75\textwidth}}
\rowcolor{white}\color{black}
\bf Column 1&\color{black}\small\bf Column 2
(continued)\cr 
\hline
\endhead
\rowcolor{white}\color{black}
\bf Column 1&\color{black}\bf Column 2\\
\endfirsthead 
\noalign{
\hrule height 1pt width\textwidth
 \vskip6pt}
```