# Tables spanning multiple pages with multiple tabulars: break in tabular

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking

### Background

I am writing a journal manuscript which limits the number of tables, hence, I want to include 3 tabular in a single table environment. Page size is A4. I have also defined C and L columntypes for convenience.  Sample code is given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable} % multipage tables
\usepackage{rotating}  %for rotating table
\usepackage{diagbox}  % used in table
\usepackage{adjustbox}  % used in table
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}  % center align the text in the table with fixed width of the column
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}  % left align the text in the table with fixed width of the column

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}  
% center align the text in the table with fixed width of the column
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}  
% left align the text in the table with fixed width of the column
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \caption{Nomenclature}
        \label{tab: Subscripts and superscripts}
        
        \begin{tabular}{@{}C{1.5cm}L{3.5cm}lC{1.5cm}L{4.5cm}@{}}
            %   \begin{tabular}{@{}cllcl@{}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Superscripts}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Subscripts}} \\ \midrule
            $n$ & n &  & $i$ & i \\
            $n$ & n &  & $i$ & i \\
            $n$ & n &  & $i$ & i \\
            $n$ & n &  & $i$ & i \\
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}{C{2cm}L{11cm}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} \\ 
            \midrule
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
            $D$ & variable \\
 \bottomrule \vspace{5mm} 
        \end{tabular}   
    
    \begin{tabular}{C{2cm}L{11cm}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Parameter}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} \\ 
            \midrule
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
        $a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
$a$ & parameter \\
 \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot of the pdf is shown below:
[image: output]

As you can see, this table cannot fit in a single page. Hence, I need to break the third table (tabular) and continue it across the next page. How to achieve this?

### Issues regarding `longtable`

Answers to several questions suggested to use the package `longtable` for this purpose, for example - [a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52334/table-breaks-spanning-multiple-pages), [b](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44145/table-spanning-multiple-pages), [c](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page), [d](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages), [e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469892/how-to-use-longtable-in-latex).

`longtable` works well for a single tabular across multiple pages but not in case of multiple tabulars.

How to continue with multiple tabular environments across multiple pages?

Comment: By replacing `tabular` with `longtable`?

Comment: I tried that: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\centering): `c' used. \centering

This was the error.

Comment: A longtable is not a float, hence you shouldn't nest it in a table environment. Also, why don't merge the last two tabulars in a single longtable, since they have the same preamble?

Comment: The three `tabular` groups don't seem to be all that closely related. Is there a reason for not using three separate `table` environments?

Comment: Or three separate longtables?  If you don't add a caption, they won't be numbered.

Comment: also please fix your example, we can not "see that it does not fit on a page" as we have no idea of your page size, nor what font size you are using nor how the `C`  or `L`column types are defined,  Can you make the example a small but _complete_ document that shows the issue.