# Allow table to split across pages

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a table that takes up more than a single page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page)

Is there a way to allow tabular environment to split across two pages? I build an environment which uses tabular, because I want to write something short in the left side, and explanations in the right side. Everything is fine until the table becomes big enough not to fit on the page it started, and then it jumps on the next page, leaving half a page blank before it. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Why don't you try the `parallel` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `longtable` and `supertab` packages provide multi page table support.

Comment: ahh. the opposition:-)

Comment: Are there things one of them can do better or in which they differ?

Comment: @doncherry: In my document, longtable produced longer tables than supertabular, which was not very good, since I wanted things to be as compact as possible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: perhaps in the last sentence one of the STs should be replaced by LT? ;-)