# How to force page break within a longtable cell when the content is too long

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Longtable: page breaks within row possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78578/longtable-page-breaks-within-row-possible)

I'm using longtable and it sometimes contains a text more than 1 page.

I couldn't figure out how to break page when it overflows.

It seems there is no way to do it by longtable. However, is there an alternative to longtable?

To illusturate, what i need is, transforming the following

[image: What longtable does]

to this one:

[image: What i want]

Thanks in advance.

*PS: Bold lines of the figures are the borders of the longtable. Note that there are only one longtable which contains 4 rows and 2 columns :)*

*PS2: I cannot add more rows since i'm using an `environment` template*

Comment: I couldn't find an answer on that post. If it cannot be done by longtable, then I need some other package to simulate it. That's why I also asked an alternative for longtable :)

Comment: Since you have only one column of data: are you using the table to draw the frame around the text or is there some other use? If it's to draw the frame, you can use `mdframed` package along with `minipage` to set the width. Something like: `\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\begin{mdframed}
text to frame 
\end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}`

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry that the figures are misleading. I have 2 columns. However, thanks for your suggestions, if I find a way to put them next to each other, i may use it.

Comment: As pointed out in the answers to other question; other than manually breaking the table, I don't think there is a way to do it.

Comment: @Alper May be a `tabbing`environment can be used. You lose the automatic running header, but you will have correct page brakes and the text lines up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have essentially the same problem with any table package, and need to break the table by hand. The problem as described in the question is very underspecified really and that's one of the problems. (The other problem is that the (lack of) features in the underlying `\halign` primitive would make it hard to mechanise this even if it were fully specified what was required.

Your images show a single column which vastly simplifies things. If you have paragraph text in a column then basically you could hope to break after the last line that fits on the page, but what about the adjacent cells in other columns? they may be text or images or any other TeX material, longtable really doesn't `know` what is in each cell, it is just an unbreakable box of content.

So it has to be up to the author really to manually decide how to split a given row up into multiple rows that allow page breaking at a suitable point.