# Long table and page breaks with multicolum

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, multicolumn

Admittedly, I've got quite and ugly and awkward looking longtable on my hands (can't think of a better approach to it really), where there's a lot of text in either of the three most-right columns.

Page breaks and longtables don't play well, at all.

I've tried a few solutions to make the "Country-Land" entry in the following example start in the page right before it, to no avail (solutions like inserting `\parfillskip=0pt \tabularnewline` to force a page break).

Any idea on how I could solve this issue would be much welcomed.

Thank you.

[image]

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,noparindent,noparskip]{bookest}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{newpxtext} % Font for document instead of obsolete Palatino
\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

% MAINMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

{\small
    \begin{longtable}
        {
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.3cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}
        }

        \caption{Dwellings \& Settlements} \label{Dwellings} \\
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Locale / Social Class Distinction}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        \multirow{-2.5}*{Region/Nation}  & Tribal/Rural & Village/Small Town  & City/Large Towns \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \caption*{\autoref{Dwellings} (\textit{Continued})} \\
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Locale / Social Class Distinction}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        \multirow{-2.5}*{Region/Nation}  & Tribal/Rural & Village/Small Town  & City/Large Towns \\
        \midrule    
        \endhead

dhsgsg, dgdsgd, drgd rgddg & grgdgdrgdgdrgdh sdrgs g wsgt s r seg rrr & dgssr  & --    \\
& \\
rg dgdrgdr, drgdgdgrd, dgdgdg, etc. & dgdgdrgdrgdgdr er gdrgergrgr edrgrg edrgdrdg drgd & drgsdrgddrg drgtrtdhrth rtyrtyrty rrtydtyd ftydty d ydrtdrdr drt r ryertdrtd drtdrtrtrt  rr & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago- never mind how long precisely- having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little \\
&\\
sgerrgdr rddtrdrs & Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically knocking people's hats off- then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can. This is my substitute for pistol and ball. & d;krjgtd;j rd;ltrd ;tjr;djgdr ljk;'rljm;'rdlr rr;'jk rk;fil;sehl erlfjkrnhls lrkgl;  & drgdrgdrgidrhlg r riohroihgorhrgoh roihrohrogihor \\
& \\
Country-land & There now is your insular city of the Manhattoes, belted round by wharves as Indian isles by coral reefs- commerce surrounds it with her surf. Right and left, the streets take you waterward. Its extreme downtown is the battery, where that noble mole is washed by waves, and cooled by breezes, which a few hours previous were out of sight of land. Look at the crowds of water-gazers there. & Circumambulate the city of a dreamy Sabbath afternoon. Go from Corlears Hook to Coenties Slip, and from thence, by Whitehall, northward. What do you see?- Posted like silent sentinels all around the town, stand thousands upon thousands of mortal men fixed in ocean reveries. Some leaning against the spiles. & But here is an artist. He desires to paint you the dreamiest, shadiest, quietest, most enchanting bit of romantic landscape in all the valley of the Saco. What is the chief element he employs? There stand his trees, each with a hollow trunk, as if a hermit and a crucifix were within; and here sleeps his meadow, and there sleep his cattle; and up from yonder cottage goes a sleepy smoke. Deep into distant woodlands winds a mazy way, reaching to overlapping spurs of mountains bathed in their hill-side blue. But though the picture lies thus tranced, and though this pine-tree shakes down its sighs like leaves upon this shepherd's head, yet all were vain, unless the shepherd's eye were fixed upon the magic stream before him. Go visit the Prairies in June, when for scores on scores of miles you wade knee-deep among Tiger-lilies- what is the one charm wanting?- Water- there is not a drop of water there! Were Niagara but a cataract of sand, would you travel your thousand miles to see it? Why did the poor poet of Tennessee, upon suddenly receiving two handfuls of silver, deliberate whether to buy him a coat, which he sadly needed, or invest his money in a pedestrian trip to Rockaway Beach? Why is almost every robust healthy boy with a robust healthy soul in him, at some time or other crazy to go to sea? Why upon your first voyage as a passenger, did you yourself feel such a mystical vibration, when first told that you and your ship were now out of sight of land? Why did the old Persians hold the sea holy? Why did the Greeks give it a separate deity, and own brother of Jove? Surely all this is not without meaning. And still deeper the meaning of that story of Narcissus, who because he could not grasp the tormenting, mild image he saw in the fountain, plunged into it and was drowned. But that same image, we ourselves see in all rivers and oceans. It is the image of the ungraspable phantom of life; and this is the key to it all. \\
\bottomrule

%   \insertTableNotes

\end{longtable}
}
%\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe this will help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78578/longtable-page-breaks-within-row-possible Might need to check with @DavidCarlisle though.

Comment: I was afraid someone would point me to David's reply ... 'cause that means getting rid of that table completely ... just when I can't think of anything better to present that data. Gonna have to think outside the box, it seems.

Comment: Would presenting the table in landscape mode be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Well, this is supposed to be a pdf in the end ... and, well, landscape would not the most practical way of presenting the text. It would definitely help with the lengths though, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing a page break seems to make an acceptable table here:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,noparindent,noparskip]{bookest}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{newpxtext} % Font for document instead of obsolete Palatino
\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

% MAINMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

{\small
    \begin{longtable}
        {
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.3cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}
        }

        \caption{Dwellings \& Settlements} \label{Dwellings} \\
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Locale / Social Class Distinction}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        \multirow{-2.5}*{Region/Nation}  & Tribal/Rural & Village/Small Town  & City/Large Towns \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \caption*{\autoref{Dwellings} (\textit{Continued})} \\
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Locale / Social Class Distinction}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        \multirow{-2.5}*{Region/Nation}  & Tribal/Rural & Village/Small Town  & City/Large Towns \\
        \midrule    
        \endhead

dhsgsg, dgdsgd, drgd rgddg &
 grgdgdrgdgdrgdh sdrgs g wsgt s r seg rrr &
 dgssr  &
 --    \\
&
 \\
rg dgdrgdr, drgdgdgrd, dgdgdg, etc. &
 dgdgdrgdrgdgdr er gdrgergrgr edrgrg edrgdrdg drgd &

 drgsdrgddrg drgtrtdhrth rtyrtyrty rrtydtyd ftydty d ydrtdrdr drt r ryertdrtd drtdrtrtrt  rr &

 Call me Ishmael. Some years ago- never mind how long precisely- having little or no money in 
my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little \\
&
\\
sgerrgdr rddtrdrs &
 Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp,
 drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin warehouses,
 and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially whenever my hypos get such an upper
 hand of me, that it requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into 
the street, and methodically knocking people's hats off- then, I account it high time to get to sea 
as soon as I can. This is my substitute for pistol and ball. &
 d;krjgtd;j rd;ltrd ;tjr;djgdr 
ljk;'rljm;'rdlr rr;'jk rk;fil;sehl erlfjkrnhls lrkgl;  &

drgdrgdrgidrhlg r riohroihgorhrgoh roihrohrogihor \\
&
 \\
Country-land &
 There now is your insular city of the Manhattoes, belted round by wharves as Indian
 isles by coral reefs- commerce surrounds it with her surf. Right and left, 
the streets take you waterward. Its extreme downtown is the battery, 
where that noble mole is washed by waves, and cooled by breezes, 
which a few hours previous were out of sight of land. Look at the crowds of water-gazers there. &
 Circumambulate the city of a dreamy Sabbath afternoon. Go from Corlears Hook to Coenties Slip, 
and from thence, by Whitehall, northward. What do you see?- Posted like silent sentinels all around the town, 
stand thousands upon thousands of mortal men fixed in ocean reveries. Some leaning against the spiles. &
 But here is an artist. He desires to paint you the dreamiest, shadiest, quietest, 
most enchanting bit of romantic landscape in all the valley of the Saco. 
What is the chief element he employs? There stand his trees, each with a hollow trunk, 
as if a hermit and a crucifix were within; and here sleeps his meadow, and there sleep his cattle;
 and up from yonder cottage goes a sleepy smoke. Deep into distant woodlands winds a mazy way, 
reaching to overlapping spurs of mountains bathed in their hill-side blue. 
But though the picture lies thus tranced, and though this pine-tree shakes down its 
sighs like leaves upon this shepherd's head,\parfillskip=0pt\tabularnewline
&
&
&
 yet all were vain, unless the shepherd's eye were fixed upon the magic stream before him.
 Go visit the Prairies in June, when for scores on scores of miles you wade knee-deep among 
Tiger-lilies- what is the one charm wanting?- Water- there is not a drop of water there! 
Were Niagara but a cataract of sand, would you travel your thousand miles to see it? 
Why did the poor poet of Tennessee, upon suddenly receiving two handfuls of silver, 
deliberate whether to buy him a coat, which he sadly needed, or invest his money in a 
pedestrian trip to Rockaway Beach? Why is almost every robust healthy boy with a robust 
healthy soul in him, at some time or other crazy to go to sea? Why upon your first 
voyage as a passenger, did you yourself feel such a mystical vibration, when first 
told that you and your ship were now out of sight of land? Why did the old Persians 
hold the sea holy? Why did the Greeks give it a separate deity, and own brother of Jove? 
Surely all this is not without meaning. And still deeper the meaning of that story of 
Narcissus, who because he could not grasp the tormenting, mild image he saw in the fountain,
 plunged into it and was drowned. But that same image, we ourselves see in all 
rivers and oceans. It is the image of the ungraspable phantom of life; 
and this is the key to it all. \\
\bottomrule

%   \insertTableNotes

\end{longtable}
}
%\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Once again, thank you, David. I had attempted to use the technique you employ in the example above, but failed. Your using that piece of code again made me re-organize a few elements and apply that code again ... and it's now working.