# Any alternatives for longtable package? (produce tables can continue to the next page)

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a program and I want to output the program results as PDF. I am considering to use LATEX to do the work. My results may contain many big tables, I just realized it is not so direct to output long tables in LATEX (for example, need longtable package).

My question is, longtable is the best solution or most popular one?  Any alternatives?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `xtab` and `supertabular` are alternatives (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/), though I cannot say how they compare to `longtable`.

Comment: `longtable` or `ltablex` is okay. is okay

Comment: Perhaps a MWE would be helpful, to test one or the other features by different packages?

Comment: longtable has one advantage over the others in that it is part of the core latex distribution so anyone who has latex has it. This is not so much an issue now as it used to be as these days most people get tex from a large distribution such as texlive which has many contributed packages as well, but it may still be a consideration if you are generating code for others to process.

Comment: `longtabu` also does this, I think, and maybe some of the other newer table packages. ctan will have a list for an appropriate topic, I'm sure.

Comment: I've made the package `cals` to support generation of decorated tables. Maybe you find it useful. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cals

Comment: Are your tables really tables? A lot of things people do with tabular can be better done with lists or other means.

Answer (score 6):

multipage table packages include at least  `longtable`, `supertabular`, `tabu`, `xtab`, `cals`. They all have good and bad points.

I do not understand your comment that it is not "direct" to output long tables. Most latex functionality is provided in class or package files that have to be referenced from the document. `table` environment and sectioning commands like `\section` require a class such as `article` for example, they are not defined in the latex format.

Of the packages mentioned above, `longtable` is part of the core latex release, but these days most people use tex from large distributions like texlive or miktex so there is not really any problem in using instead one of the contributed packages, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `longtblr` in `tabularray` over `longtable` in case someone needs it.