# Latex not showing rest of table

Tags: tables, longtable

I'm quite new to latex so pardon me. Latex is not showing the rest of my table and I don't know what Im doing wrong. I've spent 2 hours on this yet no solution. Can someone tell me what is going on please? Here is my table:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[english]{babel} %%% 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} %%% use 'pdftex' instead of 'dvips' for PDF output

% You can include more LaTeX packages here 


\begin{document}

\noindent 

\noindent 

\noindent 

\noindent 

\noindent 

\noindent 

\begin{tabular}{|p{1.2in}|p{0.5in}|p{1.0in}|p{1.0in}|} \hline 
\textbf{Requirement} & \textbf{Applicable }  & \textbf{Standard Applied }  & \textbf{Comments }  \\ \hline 
1.The devices must be designed and manufactured in such a way that, when used under the conditions and for the purposes intended, they will not compromise the clinical condition or tprotection of health and safety. & A & IEC 60903:2014 - live working. Electrical insulating gloves & Glove must be made of insulating material due to close proximity to current carrying materials. This standard is not accessible on the BSOL website so may need some help getting access... \\ \hline 
2. The solutions adopted y acknowledged state of the art.\newline In selecting the most appropriate solutions, the manufacturer must apply\newline the following principles in the following order:\newline --- elot be eliminated,\newline --- inform users of the residual risks due to any shortcomings of the\newline protection measures adopted. &  aa & aa & aa  \\ \hline
3. The devices must achieve the performances intended by the manufacturer and be designed, manufactured and packaged in such a way that they are suitable for one or more of the functions referred to in Article 1 \eqref{GrindEQ__2_} (a), as specified by the manufacturer.\newline \newline  & A & BS EN ISO 13934-1:2013 - Textiles --- Tensile properties of fabrics\newline Test: page 8 & Tensile strength of the glove must be manufactured accurately such that deformation of the glove during operation can be taken into account when processing data. \\ \hline 
4. The devices must achieve the performances intended by the manufacturer and be designed, manufactured and packaged in such a way that they are suitable for one or more of the functions referred to in Article 1 \eqref{GrindEQ__2_} (a), as specified by the manufacturer.\newline \newline  & A & BS EN ISO 13934-1:2013 - Textiles --- Tensile properties of fabrics\newline Test: page 8 & Tensile strength of the glove must be manufactured accurately such that deformation of the glove during operation can be taken into account when processing data. \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}



\textbf{}

\noindent 

\noindent 


\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page This will help you

Comment: Welcome, please read an introduction.  I have no clue why you are using noindent so often.

Comment: unrelated but don't do `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} %%% use 'pdftex' instead of 'dvips' for PDF output` just do `\usepackage{graphicx} ` the right option will be chosen automatically

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your `tabular` environment. Replace it by `longtable` environment and also, don't forget to include the `longtable` package in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[english]{babel} %%% 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} %%% use 'pdftex' instead of 'dvips' for PDF output
\usepackage{longtable}
% You can include more LaTeX packages here 


\begin{document}

\noindent 

\noindent 

\noindent 

\noindent 

\noindent 

\noindent 

\begin{longtable}{|p{1.2in}|p{0.5in}|p{1.0in}|p{1.0in}|} \hline 
\textbf{Requirement} & \textbf{Applicable }  & \textbf{Standard Applied }  & \textbf{Comments }  \\ \hline 
1.The devices must be designed and manufactured in such a way that, when used under the conditions and for the purposes intended, they will not compromise the clinical condition or tprotection of health and safety. & A & IEC 60903:2014 - live working. Electrical insulating gloves & Glove must be made of insulating material due to close proximity to current carrying materials. This standard is not accessible on the BSOL website so may need some help getting access... \\ \hline 
2. The solutions adopted y acknowledged state of the art.\newline In selecting the most appropriate solutions, the manufacturer must apply\newline the following principles in the following order:\newline --- elot be eliminated,\newline --- inform users of the residual risks due to any shortcomings of the\newline protection measures adopted. &  aa & aa & aa  \\ \hline
3. The devices must achieve the performances intended by the manufacturer and be designed, manufactured and packaged in such a way that they are suitable for one or more of the functions referred to in Article 1 \eqref{GrindEQ__2_} (a), as specified by the manufacturer.\newline \newline  & A & BS EN ISO 13934-1:2013 - Textiles --- Tensile properties of fabrics\newline Test: page 8 & Tensile strength of the glove must be manufactured accurately such that deformation of the glove during operation can be taken into account when processing data. \\ \hline 
4. The devices must achieve the performances intended by the manufacturer and be designed, manufactured and packaged in such a way that they are suitable for one or more of the functions referred to in Article 1 \eqref{GrindEQ__2_} (a), as specified by the manufacturer.\newline \newline  & A & BS EN ISO 13934-1:2013 - Textiles --- Tensile properties of fabrics\newline Test: page 8 & Tensile strength of the glove must be manufactured accurately such that deformation of the glove during operation can be taken into account when processing data. \\ \hline
 \end{longtable}



\textbf{}

\noindent 

\noindent 


\end{document}
```

with which you will get:

[image]
[image]