# Guides for typesetting tables with the tabularray package

Tags: tables, big-list, tabularray

The `LaTeX3` package `tabularray` provides a new way to typeset tables in a keyval way.
This allows the separation of content and style, which can be very usefull in a lot of cases.
However, almost all guides for typesetting tables are not written for the `tabularray` package,
making it difficult for new users to use the package.

This post aims to simplify this by providing small guides for often asked questions.
I know, that a lot of information will be similar to the
[tabularray documentation](https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf),
which also provides good examples.
However, the goal of this post is a guide/tutorial style and not just documentation.

---

Links lead to existing answers.

### How to...

- use the basic syntax for creating simple tables?
- [create cells spanning multiple columns and rows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629608/258709)
- use old and new interfaces?
- [color columns, rows, cells and lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629943/258709)
- create custom column and row types?
- [use `longtblr` for creating tables spanning multiple pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614394)
- use templates and styles to customize the table appearance?
- typeset tables with `booktabs` commands?
- use `siunitx` for columns with numeric input?

If there is anything missing or unnescessary in the list, please add or delete items.
This also helps answer writers to know, which topics are still unclear.

---

**Hints for answers**

- Provide a short description what your guide is about.
- Give context which packages have been used "traditionally" to create the output,
  e.g. `table` option of `xcolor` for coloring cells.
- If sensible, provide information for both the old and new interfaces,
  allowing users to choose which approach they prefer. I find mixing both the most flexible approach.
- Refer to the official documentation, so users know where to look if there want more advanced features.

---

<sub>PS: I am new to the idea of community wiki posts, so if there is anything wrong with this,
feel free to edit.
Maybe this list is unnescessary, because people can also use the documentation.
I just thought that a few simple guides are more accesible than the whole documentation.
If this is a stupid idea, let me know.
Also, since I am not a native speaker, you are welcome to improve my writing.</sub>

Comment: Apparently, I cannot make this post community wiki myself. If any moderators think this post is usefull, please make this community wiki.

Comment: The documentation [(texdoc link)](https://texdoc.org/serve/tabularray/0) does have "simple examples" however. (chapter 1 "overview of features"). Maybe the post is still useful, we will know by the number of upvotes over a few years.

Answer (score 12):

## Creating cells that span multiple columns or rows

---

This guide explains, how to create cells that span multiple rows using the `\SetCell` command
and `cell` key.
It is specifically intended for users which are familiar with the `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` commands.

---

Let's take a look as a simple example taken from
[here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Columns_spanning_multiple_rows).
On the left is the solution using the `tabular` environment with `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`,
while the right side shows the same table using the `tblr` environment and `\SetCell` command.

[image: tabular vs tblr]

As you can see in the code below, the syntax is very similar. `\multicolumn{<ncols>}` is replaced
by `\SetCell[c=<ncols>]` and `\multirow{<nrows>}` by `\SetCell[r=<nrows>}`. Note that you don' need
curly braces for the content when using `\SetCell`. The optional argument of `\SetCell` accepts
the keys `r=<nrows>` and `c=<ncols>`, whereas the mandatory argument if often used for setting the
alignments such as `l`, `c`, `r` and `j` for horizontal aligment and `t`, `m`, `b`, `h` and `f` for vertical aligment. See the remarks at the end of this answer for further explanation about alignment.

The mandatory argument of `\SetCell` is not limited to aligment keys. It allows for many
more usefull keys, such as the color of background and foreground. Please have a look at the table
"Keys for the Contents of Cells" in the documentation.

**Important** In this particular case, you could ditch the ampersands in row 1 after "Team sheet" and still
get the same result. However, this does not work when you have content following in the row.
This behaviour differs from `\multicolumn`, so remember this when some cells appear to vanish.
When working with large tables, it is recommended to name the unused cells, e.g. as in the second
code example below.

Additionally, the `tblr` solution has more vertical spacing between rows,
making it easier to read the table. The spacing can be controlled by several keys in the mandatory
argument, which can be found in the table "Keys for Rows" in the documentation.

```
%%% Code for tabular
%\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Team sheet} \\
    \hline
    Goalkeeper & GK & Paul Robinson \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{Defenders} & LB & Lucas Radebe \\
    & DC & Michael Duburry \\
    & DC & Dominic Matteo \\
    & RB & Didier Domi \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Midfielders} & MC & David Batty \\
    & MC & Eirik Bakke \\
    & MC & Jody Morris \\ \hline
    Forward & FW & Jamie McMaster \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Strikers} & ST & Alan Smith \\
    & ST & Mark Viduka \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

%%% Code for tblr
%\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{tblr}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \SetCell[c=3]{c} Team sheet && \\
    \hline
    Goalkeeper & GK & Paul Robinson \\ \hline
    \SetCell[r=4]{l} Defenders some really & LB & Lucas Radebe \\
    & DC & Michael Duburry \\
    & DC & Dominic Matteo \\
    & RB & Didier Domi \\ \hline
    \SetCell[r=3]{l} Midfielders & MC & David Batty \\
    & MC & Eirik Bakke \\
    & MC & Jody Morris \\ \hline
    Forward & FW & Jamie McMaster \\ \hline
    \SetCell[r=2]{l} Strikers & ST & Alan Smith \\
    & ST & Mark Viduka \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
```

---

### Using the new keyval interface of tabularray

Every aspect of formatting the table can also be controlled via the new keyval interface in the
mandatory argument of `\begin{tblr}`. For example, if you want to typeset the exact same table as
in the previous `tabular` solution, you could do something like this.

```
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec=lll, rowsep=0pt,
        vlines, hline{1,2,3,7,10,11,13},
        cell{1}{1}={c=3}{c}, cell{3}{1}={r=4}{l},
        cell{7}{1}={r=3}{l}, cell{11}{1}={r=2}{l},
    }
    Team sheet & 1-2 & 1-3 \\
    Goalkeeper & GK & Paul Robinson \\
    Defenders & LB & Lucas Radebe \\
    4-1 & DC & Michael Duburry \\
    5-1 & DC & Dominic Matteo \\
    6-1 & RB & Didier Domi \\
    Midfielders & MC & David Batty \\
    8-1 & MC & Eirik Bakke \\
    9-1 & MC & Jody Morris \\
    Forward & FW & Jamie McMaster \\
    Strikers & ST & Alan Smith \\
    12-1 & ST & Mark Viduka \\
\end{tblr}
```

When using multiple keys, you have to put the columns specification in the key `colspec`.
`rowsep=0pt` removes the extra vertical spacing (this is just an example, please consider keeping
the spacing as it makes the table more readable). The `vlines` and `hline` keys are for the vertical
and horizontal lines respectively. The `\SetCell[<span>{<styles>}` at cell in row `i` and `j`
is replaced by the option `cell{i}{j}={<span>}{<styles>}`. Note the curly braces for `<span>`.
The unused cells are also numbered with their respective row and column number. This makes it easier
to keep track of ampersands when working with large tables. The content of these cells is ignored
for typesetting.

As you can see, the format is now completely separated from the content. This can be very usefull,
e.g. when you get your table data from an external ressource. For a full comparision between the
two interfaces, read the table "Old Interfaces and New Interfaces" in the documentation.

You can mix both interfaces in your `tblr` environment as you like. For example, you can choose
spacing and horizontal and vertical lines in the New Interface and use the `\SetCell` command in
the old interface.

---

That concludes the short introduction to typesetting multicolumn and multirow cells using the
`tabularray` package. If you think there is something wrong or missing, feel free to improve
this answer.

---

**Remark 1**: For a multirow cell, vertical aligment `t`, `m` and `b` are the same: any one of them will put cell text in the middle. You may use `h` or `f` alignment if you want to align the top/bottom baseline of a multirow cell with that of a single-row cell in another column.

**Remark 2**: For a single-row cell, default vertical aligment is `t` (top), while for a multirow cell, default vertical aligment is `m` (middle).

Comment: Thanks for adding this information. I was just browsing through the code, if there is a different vertical alignment when `r>1`, because I stumbled on this while writing the answer.

Comment: I have added two remarks which are missing in the documentation to the end of your answer. Feel free to move them to the appropriate positions.

Answer (score 10):

## Coloring columns, rows, cells and lines

---

This guide explains how to use colors in `tblr` tables. You will learn how to color columns, rows,
individual cells and horizontal and vertical lines. For users familiar with the `\columncolor`,
`\rowcolor` and `cellcolor` commands, analogous `tabularray` commands will be provided.

---

Let's take a look at a ugly but colorfull example.
On the left is the solution using the `tabular` environment with commands defined by
`\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, while the right side shows the same table using the `tblr`
environment.

[image: tabular vs tblr colored tables]

Excerpt for some extra vertical spacing, the tables look identical. In the code below, you can
also see that the code is very similar. `\rowcolor` and `\cellcolor` are replaced by
`\SetRow` and `\SetCell` respectively. Note that `\SetRow` is not needed in row 1, because the
color is set in the `\SetCell` command.

Coloring columns is done with `\columncolor` in the
`xcolor` syntax. A user can use `>` in the column definition or define a new column type, e.q.
the `a` column in the example. With `tabularray`, you can specify  a color using the primitive
`Q` column type. Of course, you can also define a new column type with `\NewColumnType`, see
column `A` for an example. **Note** The `Q` column type supports usefull keys, e.g. vertical
alignment, font color and many more. See the table "Keys for Columns"  in the documentation.

The appearance of horizontal and vertical lines in `tabular` environment can be customized by
commands such as `\arrayrulewidth` and `\arrayrulecolor`. `tabularray` provides see keys `hlines`
and `vlines` for setting horizontal and vertical lines respectively. Note that you don't need the
`\hline` commands in the table content.

```
%%% Code for tabular
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{a}{ >{\columncolor{yellow!50}} l }
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\begin{tabular}{|a|>{\columncolor{red!50}}r|r|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{green} \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{{\LARGE \textcolor{red}{StackExchange Sites}}} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!50} Site & questions & answers \\ \hline
    Stack Overflow & 22m & 33m \\ \hline
    Mathematics & 1.5m & \cellcolor{magenta} 2m \\ \hline
    Super User & 472k & 684k \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{orange!50} TeX - LaTeX & 228k & 293k \\ \hline
\end{tabular

%%% Code for tblr
%\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewColumnType{A}{Q[l, yellow!50]}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={AQ[r,red!50]r}, hlines={2pt, gray}, vlines={2pt, gray}}
    \SetCell[c=3]{c, green, fg=red, font=\LARGE} StackExchange Sites && \\
    \SetRow{blue!50} Site & questions & answers \\
    Stack Overflow & 22m & 33m \\
    Mathematics & 1.5m & \SetCell{magenta} 2m \\
    Super User &  472k & 684k \\
    \SetRow{orange!50} TeX - LaTeX & 228k & 293k \\
\end{tblr}
```

**Remark** Small lines are sometimes not correctly rendered, when using the `xcolor` commands.
Additionaly, `\cline` commands don't work. Both of these issues are not present when using the
`tabularray` syntax.

---

### Using the new keyval interface of tabularray

`tabularray` also has a new keyval interface allowing you to customize the format of the table in the
mandatory argument of `\begin{tblr}`. Using this new syntax, the table can be created with

```
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec={lrr}, hlines={2pt, gray}, vlines={2pt, gray},
        column{1} = {yellow!50}, column{2} = {red!50},
        row{2} = {blue!50}, row{Z} = {orange!50},
        cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{c, green, fg=red, font=\LARGE},
        cell{4}{3} = {magenta},
    }
    StackExchange Sites && \\
    Site & questions & answers \\
    Stack Overflow & 22m & 33m \\
    Mathematics & 1.5m & 2m \\
    Super User &  472k & 684k \\
    TeX - LaTeX & 228k & 293k \\
\end{tblr}
```

You can specify columns and rows using the `column` and `row` keys respectively. The
`\SetCell[<span>{<styles>}` at cell in row `i` and `j` is replaced by the option
`cell{i}{j}={<span>}{<styles>}`. For example, `cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{c, green, fg=red, font=\LARGE}`
sets the cell in the first row and column to span 3 columns `{c=3}`, centered `c`, with `green`
background color, `red` font color and `LARGE` font. For a full list of options, have a look at the
tables "Keys for the Content of Cells", "Keys for Rows" and "Keys for Columns" in the documentation.

You can mix both interfaces in your `tblr` environment as you like. For example, you can specify the
`columns` and `rows` keys and use the `\SetCell` for customizing individual cells.

---

### Color alternating rows

Another often wanted style is to color alternating rows with different colors. With
`\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` you can use the command `\rowcolors{<start-row>}{<odd-row-color>}{<even-row-color>}`
for this. `tabularray` provides the selectors `odd` and `even`, which can be used in the `row` and
`column` keys. As of now, specifying `odd` and `even` from a specified starting index is not supported.
The feature will be added soon (see [here](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/105)). In the
meantime you have to override the cells which should not be colored, as in the example below.

```
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec={lrr}, hlines,
        row{even} = {blue!20},
        row{odd} = {red!20},
        row{1} = {white, font=\large\bfseries},
    }
    Site & questions & answers \\
    Stack Overflow & 22m & 33m \\
    Mathematics & 1.5m & 2m \\
    Super User &  472k & 684k \\
    TeX - LaTeX & 228k & 293k \\
\end{tblr}
```

[image: color alternating rows]

---

**Advanced examples**

The `odd` and `even` selectors can also produce more complex patterns, e.g. a
[chesboard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611587/258709).

Very advanced users can also define custom selectors with `\NewChildSelector` (see an
[example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629881/258709)), but that is beyond the scope of this guide.

---

That concludes the short introduction for using colors with the `tabularray` package.
If you think there is something wrong or missing, feel free to improve
this answer.

Comment: In fact, `\columncolor,` `\rowcolor` and `\cellcolor` commands are provided by `colortbl` package. And `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` loads `colortbl` package. To typeset colorful tables, `colortbl` needs `color` or `xcolor` package, and `tabularray` need `xcolor` and `ninecolors` packages.